# Send link from my controller to Jquery

Tags: symfony

I wanted to send generated links from my controller to jquery, but it doesn't work because of the function : path, I made like this:

```
$html = '<a href="{{ path("cs_Content", {"tId": "'.$tnum.'"}) }}">'.$tname.'...</a>';
```

**Question** Is this right how i wrote or should I write the link without path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is a twig function. In controller you have to use php functions of course:

```
$html = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->generateUrl('cs_content', array('tId' => $tnum), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL), $tname);
```

Here I generate an absolute url, because it's more save to use absolute urls in client side (struggled with relatives url in past from time to time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing Twig and php notation.

```
    $link = $this->generateUrl('cs_Content', array(
        'tId' => $tnum,
    ));

    $html = '<a href="' . $link . '">'.$tname.'...</a>';
```